# Angular-Slick with Grunt

Tags: javascript, angularjs, gruntjs, yeoman, slick.js

I'm having a really tough time getting [Angular-Slick](https://github.com/devmark/angular-slick-carousel) to load properly on my page after it has been built by Grunt using the [Yeoman Angular generator](https://github.com/yeoman/generator-angular). When I serve the file locally everything looks perfect, but somewhere along the line after minification/uglify it all goes pear shaped. It should look like this, and does when served:

[image]

Here is what everything looks like after it has been built and hosted. The images are not even visible at all and it seems like they are stacking each other out of the view: http://jamesiv.es/alpha

Dependancies:

```
{
  "name": "v2",
  "version": "0.0.0",
  "dependencies": {
    "angular": "^1.3.0",
    "bootstrap-sass-official": "^3.2.0",
    "angular-resource": "^1.3.0",
    "angular-route": "^1.3.0",
    "angular-google-maps": "~2.1.5",
    "angular-bootstrap": "~0.13.1",
    "particles.js": "~2.0.0",
    "slick-carousel": "~1.5.8",
    "angular-slick-carousel": "~3.0.2"
  },
  "devDependencies": {
    "angular-mocks": "^1.3.0"
  },
  "appPath": "app",
  "moduleName": "v2App",
  "overrides": {
    "bootstrap": {
      "main": [
        "less/bootstrap.less",
        "dist/css/bootstrap.css",
        "dist/js/bootstrap.js"
      ]
    }
  },
  "resolutions": {
    "angular": "^1.3.0"
  }
}
```

Gruntfile:

```
 grunt.registerTask('build', [
    'clean:dist',
    'wiredep',
    'useminPrepare',
    'concurrent:dist',
    'autoprefixer',
    'ngtemplates',
    'concat',
    'ngAnnotate',
    'copy:dist',
    'cdnify',
    'cssmin',
    'uglify',
    'filerev',
    'usemin',
    'htmlmin'
  ]);
```

'slickCarousel' is injected into the module. Here is the main controller used for Slick:

```
angular.module('v2App')
  .controller('MainCtrl', function ($scope) {

    $scope.images = [
      "images/logos/angular.png",
      "images/logos/android.png",
      "images/logos/appengine.png",
      "images/logos/atom.png",
      "images/logos/bootstrap.png",
      "images/logos/bower.png"
      ];
  });
```

I have Slick rendering from a view like so with my App configured for the correct page:

```
  <body ng-app="v2App">
    <div ng-view="" class="content"></div>
  </body>
```

And then I have Slick inside my view. I have defined "images" as the data as that's where it's pulling the images from:

```
  <div class="row">
    <div class="col-lg-12">
      <slick data="images" dots="false" infinite="true" speed="300" slides-to-show="5" touch-move="false" slides-to-scroll="1">
        <div ng-repeat="image in images">
            <img class="img-responsive" src="{{image}}">
        </div>
      </slick>
    </div>
  </div>
```

I've tried a number of fixes for this such as using $timeout and using the data-load toggle but nothing seems to fix it. I'm almost certain this is caused by Grunt but I could be wrong.

Any suggestions would be appreciated. I'm rather stuck.

Comment: I think you are having a CSS issue... is this resolved yet?

Comment: @JohnSpiteri Sadly I never figured this one out. I ended up implementing my own solution for it.

Answer (score 0):

Here is the CSS that I use, without it... it will Angular Slick will break.
If you are still interested in using it... It is a great library, that I use over and over, so worth getting it working for your tool box.

```
.slick-slider
    display: block
    float left
    width 100%
    height 160px
    overflow hidden
    padding: 0
    margin: 0 0 10px 0
    background $white
    border-top $black-border
    border-bottom $black-border
    box-sizing: border-box
    -moz-box-sizing: border-box
    -webkit-touch-callout: none
    -webkit-user-select: none
    -khtml-user-select: none
    -moz-user-select: none
    -ms-user-select: none
    user-select: none
    -ms-touch-action: none
    -webkit-tap-highlight-color: transparent
    z-index 99

.slick-list
    position: relative
    overflow: hidden
    display: block
    margin: 0
    padding: 0

.slick-list:focus
    outline: none

.slick-loading .slick-list
    background: white url("../img/ajax-loader.gif") center center no-repeat

.slick-list.dragging
    cursor: pointer
    cursor: hand

.slick-slider .slick-list,
.slick-track,
.slick-slide,
.slick-slide img
    -webkit-transform: translate3d(0, 0, 0)
    -moz-transform: translate3d(0, 0, 0)
    -ms-transform: translate3d(0, 0, 0)
    -o-transform: translate3d(0, 0, 0)
    transform: translate3d(0, 0, 0)

.slick-track
    position: relative
    left: 0
    top: 0
    display: block
    zoom: 1

.slick-track:before,
.slick-track:after
    content: ""
    display: table

.slick-track:after
    clear: both

.slick-loading .slick-track
    visibility: hidden

.slick-slide
    float: left
    height: 100%
    min-height: 1px
    display: none

.slick-slide img
    display: block

.slick-slide.slick-loading img
    display: none

.slick-slide video
    display: block

.slick-slide video.slick-loading
    display: none

.slick-slide.dragging img
    pointer-events: none

.slick-initialized .slick-slide
    display: block

.slick-loading .slick-slide
    visibility: hidden

.slick-vertical .slick-slide
    display: block
    height: auto
```

If all is good prior to minification, then I would suggest wrapping up the "angular-slick/dist/slick.js" and "slick-carousel/slick/slick.js" in an IIFE!

Here is the [file](https://github.com/vasyabigi/angular-slick/blob/master/dist/slick.js) in the repo, and it is not minification friendly...